# Inserting in a WStandardItemModel is too slow

Tags: c++, wt

I am working on a application built uppon WT.

We have a performance problem, as it must display a lot of data in a WTableView associated with a WStandardItemModel.

For each new item to be added in the table it does:

```
model->setData( row, column, data )
```

(which happens a few thousand times).

Is there some way to make it faster? some other way to add data in the table?

it can take 2 seconds to generate the data and several minutes to display it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WStandardItemModel is a general-purpose model that is easy to use, but it's not optimal for very large models. Try to specialize a WAbstractTableModel; you only need to reimplement three methods and you can read your data from wherever it resides, or compute it on the fly.

It's not normal that a view takes minutes to display. I've used views on tables with many thousands of entries without performance problems. Was your system swapping because of the memory wasted in a (extremely large) WStandardItemModel?